# Crash on json parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm unable to parse this json:

```
{
"dati": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Perugia01"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Perugia02"
    }
]
}
```

I'm trying with:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager GET:path parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

     NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;

     NSMutableArray *firstZero = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [firstZero addObject:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"dati"]];

     NSMutableDictionary *weatherDict = [firstZero objectAtIndex:0];

     NSString *codice = [weatherDict objectForKey:@"id"];  //Here I got a crash
     NSString *nome = [weatherDict objectForKey:@"nome"];

     NSLog(@"Codice cantiere: %@\nNome cantiere: %@",codice, nome);
 }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
 {
     // Failure
     NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
     NSString *errore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error];
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Errore" message:errore delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
 }];
```

but I got a crash with this message:

```
[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1a6ee0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1a6ee0'
```

I can't understand what's wrong.
It seems there's a problem with the objectforkey, but I don't know why.
 Could you please help me to figure it out?

Comment: objectForKey is a dictionary method, not a array one. Your problem is that you expect an dictionary but you get an array.

Comment: change NSMutableDictionary *weatherDict = [firstZero objectAtIndex:0]; To NSMutableArray *weatherArray=[firstZero objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Do you know how to read JSON?  Go to json.org and learn the syntax.  (And why insert that value into `firstZero` and then pull it right back out again, vs just using a simple pointer to the object?  I suspect you're just modifying code you don't understand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing an array not a dictionary:

```
[manager GET:path parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

     NSArray *dati  = [responseObject objcForKey:@"dati"]];

     for (NSDictionary *datiDict in dati) {
         NSString *codice = [datiDict objectForKey:@"id"];  //Here I got a crash
         NSString *nome = [datiDict objectForKey:@"nome"];

         NSLog(@"Codice cantiere: %@\nNome cantiere: %@",codice, nome);
     }

 }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
 {
     // Failure
     NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
     NSString *errore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error];
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Errore" message:errore delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

In JSON Structure,

when you got

**{ means Dictionary**

**[ means Array**

So based on that, object for "dati" is Array.

Array doesn't have the method like objectForKey: That's why you are getting crash.

Use dictionary for that & follow up the rckoenes answer

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with following two lines,

```
 NSMutableArray *firstZero = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [firstZero addObject:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"dati"]];
```

The key "dati" contains an array,  and you are adding that array as the first object of the `firstZero` mutable array. This means your first object is not an NSDictionary but another Array.

So `[firstZero objectAtIndex:0];` will not return a dictionary . That's why you can not call `[datiDict objectForKey:@"id"];` because `datiDict` is an array, not a dictionary.

**Solution:** Simply change above two lines to following,

```
 NSMutableArray *firstZero = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 firstZero = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"dati"]];
```

Comment: Why "initialize" `firstZero` if you're going to overwrite it in the very next line??